# Использование AsyncLocalStorage в приложении Node.js

Tags: node.js

Предположим, есть простое приложение на Node.js и Express. Я не могу понять, зачем может понадобиться `AsyncLocalStorage` (Пример 1), если все тоже самое я могу получить без его использования (Пример 2).

Из документации следует, что `AsyncLocalStorage` лучше работает с памятью и более оптимизирован. Это причина для его использования?

Пример 1:

```
const express = require('express');
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require('async_hooks');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

const requestIdMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  asyncLocalStorage.run(new Map(), () => {
    asyncLocalStorage.getStore().set('requestId', uuidv4());
    next();
  });
};

const app = express();

app.use(requestIdMiddleware);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const id = asyncLocalStorage.getStore().get('requestId');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`[${id}] request received`);
  }, 0);
  res.send('Ok');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}`));
```

Пример 2:

```
const express = require('express');
const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const store = new Map().set('requestId', uuidv4())
    const id = store.get('requestId');
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`[${id}] request received`);
    }, 0);
    res.send('Ok');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67151337/4496422

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AsyncLocalStorage](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_class_asynclocalstorage) — это класс, который используется для хранения некоего состояния (контекста) в рамках некоего одного асинхронного действия (которое может включать в себя много "внутренних" асинхронных действий).

Хорошо иллюстрируется на обработчике запроса. Будем считать, что "обработка запроса" и есть то самое "асинхронного действие", так вот, - контекст будет доступен в любой момент обработки запроса откуда бы его не запросили. Вы можете запросить контекст в роутере, можете запросить его в любом подключаемом модуле, в контексте, промисе и т.д. - и это будет один и тот же контекст.

Для иллюстрации напишем middleware, которая будет запускать обработку запроса express внутри асинхронного хука

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const requestId = uuidv4();
  const startTime = Date.now();
  asyncLocalStorage.run({ requestId, startTime }, () => {
    logger.log('BEGIN');
    next();
  });
  res.on('finish', () => logger.log(`END [REQ_TIME=${(Date.now() - startTime) / 1000}s]`));
});
```

Напишем классический обработчик ошибок express, в котором запросим `store` у asyncLocalStorage:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
  if (store) {
    logger.error(`FAIL [REQ_TIME=${(Date.now() - store.startTime) / 1000}s]`, err);
  } else {
    logger.error('FAIL ', err);
  }
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'SOMETHING_WRONG' });
});
```

Напишем логгер, вместо привычного `console.log` и будем использовать его где-то, где нет `express`, `req`, `res` и т.п.

```
const logger = {
  log: (...args) => {
    const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
    if (store) {
      args.unshift(`[REQUEST_ID=${store.requestId}]`);
    }
    console.log(...args);
  },
  error: (...args) => {
    const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
    if (store) {
      args.unshift(`[REQUEST_ID=${store.requestId}]`);
    }
    console.error(...args);
  }
};
```

Напишем функцию, имитирующую что-то асинхронное и очень программистское, иногда она будет возвращать ошибку. А ещё она будет пользоваться логгером, проверим что там с контекстами!

```
async function apiCall1(x) {
  await setTimeout(500);
  if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
    throw new Error('BUMP');
  }
  logger.log('YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1');
  return apiCall2(x);
}

async function apiCall2(x) {
  await setTimeout(500);
  logger.log('YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2');
  return { ok: x };
}
```

И соединим всё вместе:

```
const express = require('express');
const { setTimeout } = require('timers/promises');
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require('async_hooks');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

const logger = {
  log: (...args) => {
    const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
    if (store) {
      args.unshift(`[REQUEST_ID=${store.requestId}]`);
    }
    console.log(...args);
  },
  error: (...args) => {
    const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
    if (store) {
      args.unshift(`[REQUEST_ID=${store.requestId}]`);
    }
    console.error(...args);
  }
};

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const requestId = uuidv4();
  const startTime = Date.now();
  asyncLocalStorage.run({ requestId }, () => {
    logger.log('BEGIN');
    next();
  });
  res.on('finish', () => logger.log(`END [REQ_TIME=${(Date.now() - startTime) / 1000}s]`));
});

app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await apiCall1(Date.now());
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
  if (store) {
    logger.error(`FAIL [REQ_TIME=${(Date.now() - store.startTime) / 1000}s]`, err);
  } else {
    logger.error('FAIL ', err);
  }
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'SOMETHING_WRONG' });
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}`));

async function apiCall1(x) {
  await setTimeout(500);
  if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
    throw new Error('BUMP');
  }
  logger.log('YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1');
  return apiCall2(x);
}

async function apiCall2(x) {
  await setTimeout(500);
  logger.log('YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2');
  return { ok: x };
}
```

Отправим на сервер сотню запросов в десяти потоках:

```
~ $ ab -n 100 -c 10 http://localhost:3000/
```

Вывод в консоль:

```bsh
[REQUEST_ID=e31afb8a-c264-498d-92d7-9925af9f69ad] END [REQ_TIME=0.504s]
[REQUEST_ID=81189ba3-4470-4d8c-9379-3c2476ce193b] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=089a211e-df40-4d54-9f9c-bed2f0079775] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=3b4cd2d6-35d8-423c-9f95-a057b7bef2df] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=a96a3d23-a689-4c0b-8ebb-3525e1cc4c0b] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=b2113359-ef72-4f7d-9c6c-3a3759622dd7] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=e3061eea-58d3-4130-baf0-52fc4fc2c064] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=f3dc636d-c56f-4520-9609-ff69d59ff97f] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=ab8df496-bd1f-473a-b362-9db71d8d1c5f] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=c4d5adc4-5ba4-409c-bd6f-1b2f0d7be3d7] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=2b78b8be-af48-4425-9099-1c0cca0cef0c] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=81189ba3-4470-4d8c-9379-3c2476ce193b] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2
[REQUEST_ID=81189ba3-4470-4d8c-9379-3c2476ce193b] END [REQ_TIME=1.011s]
[REQUEST_ID=089a211e-df40-4d54-9f9c-bed2f0079775] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=3b4cd2d6-35d8-423c-9f95-a057b7bef2df] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=a96a3d23-a689-4c0b-8ebb-3525e1cc4c0b] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=b2113359-ef72-4f7d-9c6c-3a3759622dd7] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=e3061eea-58d3-4130-baf0-52fc4fc2c064] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=f3dc636d-c56f-4520-9609-ff69d59ff97f] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=ab8df496-bd1f-473a-b362-9db71d8d1c5f] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=c4d5adc4-5ba4-409c-bd6f-1b2f0d7be3d7] FAIL [REQ_TIME=0.502s] Error: BUMP
    at apiCall1 (/Users/nörbörnën/git/stackoverflow-practice/src/asynclocalstorage-1/index.js:63:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
    at async /Users/nörbörnën/git/stackoverflow-practice/src/asynclocalstorage-1/index.js:40:18
[REQUEST_ID=c4d5adc4-5ba4-409c-bd6f-1b2f0d7be3d7] END [REQ_TIME=0.503s]
[REQUEST_ID=2b78b8be-af48-4425-9099-1c0cca0cef0c] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall1
[REQUEST_ID=3ef7e502-fe61-4565-8029-46c0afa6c162] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=ade7f232-ebd0-466f-b9f6-879959dcc7f3] BEGIN
[REQUEST_ID=089a211e-df40-4d54-9f9c-bed2f0079775] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2
[REQUEST_ID=089a211e-df40-4d54-9f9c-bed2f0079775] END [REQ_TIME=1.009s]
[REQUEST_ID=3b4cd2d6-35d8-423c-9f95-a057b7bef2df] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2
[REQUEST_ID=3b4cd2d6-35d8-423c-9f95-a057b7bef2df] END [REQ_TIME=1.009s]
[REQUEST_ID=a96a3d23-a689-4c0b-8ebb-3525e1cc4c0b] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2
[REQUEST_ID=a96a3d23-a689-4c0b-8ebb-3525e1cc4c0b] END [REQ_TIME=1.009s]
[REQUEST_ID=b2113359-ef72-4f7d-9c6c-3a3759622dd7] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2
[REQUEST_ID=b2113359-ef72-4f7d-9c6c-3a3759622dd7] END [REQ_TIME=1.009s]
[REQUEST_ID=e3061eea-58d3-4130-baf0-52fc4fc2c064] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2
[REQUEST_ID=e3061eea-58d3-4130-baf0-52fc4fc2c064] END [REQ_TIME=1.01s]
[REQUEST_ID=f3dc636d-c56f-4520-9609-ff69d59ff97f] YAHOOOOO INSIDE apiCall2
[REQUEST_ID=f3dc636d-c56f-4520-9609-ff69d59ff97f] END [REQ_TIME=1.011s]
```

---

> **Я не могу понять, зачем может понадобиться AsyncLocalStorage (Пример 1), если все тоже самое я могу получить без его использования (Пример 2).**

Без AsyncLocalStorage вы сможете провернуть, но для этого вам прийдется везде передавать и принимать этот контекст: middleware - роутер - apiCall1 - apiCall2, везде. А с AsyncLocalStorage всё стало проще.

---

Выше был приведён понятный и простой пример использования контекста, пример для ответа на ваш вопрос. Теперь же посмотрим на что-то вкусное и современное. `AsyncLocalStorage` и `dependency injection container`? -  ЛЕГКО!

Вот, например, интересная `orm` [mikro-orm](https://mikro-orm.io/) пишет в свой документации:

> Если вы используете контейнер для внедрения зависимостей, такой как
> inversify или тот, что в nestjs framework, этого может быть трудно
> достичь, потому что **вы обычно хотите получить доступ к своим
> репозиториям через контейнер DI, но он всегда будет предоставлять вам
> один и тот же экземпляр, а не новый для каждого запроса**.
>
> Чтобы решить эту проблему, вы можете использовать helper
>
> RequestContext, который будет использовать node domain API в фоновом
> режиме для изоляции контекста запроса. **MikroORM всегда будет
> использовать менеджер сущностей для конкретного запроса
> (форкнутый), если он доступен, поэтому все, что вам нужно сделать,
> это создать новый контекст запроса**, предпочтительно в middleware.

Итак, они хотят, чтобы для каждого запроса существовал отдельный контекст с коллекцией репозиториев и сущностей. `AsyncLocalStorage`? - [Ага!](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/async-local-storage/)

> Начиная с версии v4.0.3, вы также можете использовать новый
> AsyncLocalStorage:

```
const storage = new AsyncLocalStorage<EntityManager>();

const orm = await MikroORM.init({
  context: () => storage.getStore(),
  // ...
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  storage.run(orm.em.fork(true, true), next);
});
```

Результат выполнения `orm.em.fork(true, true)`, то есть целый `EntityManager`, становится `store`-ом. Шикарно же.

Comment: Вау, спасибо большое за столь развернутый ответ!

Comment: @SergeyIsaev я там ещё вбросил! хорошая штука, этот AsyncLocalStorage.