# Как создать глобальную переменную которую можно будет использовать и изменять по всему проекту в nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как создать глобальную переменную которую можно будет использовать и изменять по всему проекту в nodejs?

Comment: для этого можно использовать AsyncLocalStorage https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1271813/2659

Comment: Положить её в global. Но вообще идея так себе

Comment: Ещё можно использовать переменные окружения + [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env), если к вашему случаю подходит.