# Как измерить среднее время запроса к приложению node js?

Tags: node.js, nginx

**Имею такую архитектуру**:

`docker-compose`. В нем работает **3 сервиса**: `nginx`, `api`, `mysql`. `Api` - **nodejs/express**.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было получить среднее время доступа по каждому из роутов `api`.

**Например**:

```
GET: site/users - AVERAGE: 100 ms.
POST: site/users - AVERAGE: 122 ms.
GET: site/news - AVERAGE: 50 ms.
GET: site/news - AVERAGE: 52 ms.
```

Думал сделать свою функцию для [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) , сохраняя данные в объект формата: `{URL: [ms, ms]}`

Какие есть решения?

Comment: можно записывать в лог nginx [$upstream_response_time](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_response_time), потом анализировать логи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
import express from "express";
import logger from "morgan";

const app = express();


const Storage = {};
    app.use(logger((tokens, req, res) => {
        const averageCalc = (array) => {
            const sum = array.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0);
            return (sum / array.length) || 0;
        };

    const prepareStorageObjectMutate = (object, params) => {
        const {url, method} = params;

        object[url] = object[url] || {};
        object[url][method] = object[url][method] || [];

        return object;
    };

    const averageTimeHandler = (data) => {
        const result = {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach((url) => {

            Object.keys(data[url]).forEach((method) => {
                prepareStorageObjectMutate(result, {method, url});
                const dataArray = data[url][method];
                const average = averageCalc(dataArray);

                result[url][method] = `${average} ms`;
            });

        });
        return result;
    };

    try {
        const {method: methodF, url: urlF, "response-time": responseTimeF} = tokens;

        //Resolve data.
        const method = methodF(req, res);
        const url = urlF(req, res);
        const responseTime = responseTimeF(req, res);

        prepareStorageObjectMutate(Storage, {method, url});

        //Push response time.
        Storage[url][method].push(responseTime);
        const averageObject = averageTimeHandler(Storage);

        console.log(Storage);

        return JSON.stringify(averageObject);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Logger error:");
        console.log(error);
    }
}));
```

Пример:

```
{"/api/users":{"GET":"6.098857142857144 ms"},"/api/news":{"GET":"2.579153846153846 ms"},"/api/users/login":{"POST":"183.39033333333336 ms"}}
```

Comment: если nodejs свежий, [есть способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1285073/2659) не изобретать велосипед