# Как правильно реализовать доступ к экземпляру класса?

Tags: node.js

У меня есть класс, например:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(param) {
    this.param = param;
  }
  async method() {
    return;
  }
}
```

Далее при старте сервера мне нужно подгрузить данные из бд и создать экземпляры класса:

```
const express = require('express');
...
let classes = {};
data.map(el => classes[el.id] = new MyClass(el.param));
```

Вопрос вот в чем, как мне иметь доступ к экземплярам класса в переменной `classes` в других частях моего приложения? Создавать глобальную переменную и в ней хранить данные? Или есть какие-то инструменты для этого? Т.к слышал, что нужно избегать глобальных переменных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если этих частей не много, то просто передавайте в них этот объект с экземплярами. Или измените подход, чтобы глобальность не требовалась.

В глобальных переменных нет ничего страшного. Экспресс сам пронизан аналогами глобальных переменных (req res). Если будете их избегать, но доступ глобальный будет, то будете их просто называть под другим соусом типа синглтона или ключа-подключа в global или статичных полей какого-то класса.

Одна из прелестей node в глобальных переменных, которые видны сквозь все запросы. Так легко сделать кеши или связь двух запросов. Если конечно их изоляция не требуется.

Comment: а ещё можно было посоветовать AsyncLocalStorage [:)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1285073/2659)